# How do I merge two datasets based on the common key in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, foreign-keys, merging-data

I have two datasets that contains domain names:

df1:

```
varA     domains            
123     www.google.com   
456     www.ebay.com     
789     www.amazon.com   
101     www.nbc.com      
....
```

df2:

```
 urls            varB
www.cnn.com      xsd
www.ebay.com     wer
www.nbc.com      xyz
www.amazon.com   zyx
....
```

I need to populate urls values in df2 with varA values from df1 for the matching domains/urls, so the output would look like this:

```
 urls            varA   varB
www.ebay.com     456    wer
www.nbc.com      101    xyz
www.amazon.com   789    zyx
....
```

All of the domains in df2 that do not have a matching domain in df1 should be removed.

I have this code:

```
target_cols = ['domains', 'urls', 'varB', 'varA']
df2.merge(df1[target_cols], on='urls', how='inner')
```

The code is generating an error.

How do I fix it? Any alternative solutions that can work?

Comment: This particular question is answered by the section in the linked duplicate target, under the section "Avoiding duplicate key column in output".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because keys on which you are merging do not have same name
This will work

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = 'domains', right_on = 'urls', how = 'inner').drop('domains', axis = 1)


    varA    urls            varB
0   456     www.ebay.com    wer
1   789     www.amazon.com  zyx
2   101     www.nbc.com     xyz
```

Comment: Partially worked, varB did not get transferred

Comment: Are you not getting the same output as what I printed?

Comment: only varA and urls, varB is not in the output

Comment: The merge will merge all the columns as long as they are in the original df. I can't get what happened to varB. Can you once again print df1 and df2 and check. I am pretty confident that this code works

Comment: You are correct, my apologies - was trying to print the misspelled variable. It is working!